# Graph theory proposition proof using induction

Tags: logic, graph-theory, induction

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $v:=|V|, e:=|E|.$ Then a result in graph theory says that if $G$ is connected, then $v-1 \leq e$. The proof I know uses induction over $v$. I wondered, however, why this statement is provable by induction formally. This statement seems to not quantify over $v \in \mathbf{N}$ directly and even if it did, it would contain a property that would contain $e$ as a variable too (is it allowed that the property $P$ contains other variables too?). I don't know how one would formally express this proposition and then proof it formally by induction. Thanks in advance for any help.

If it is needed, I can post the full proof here. However, since the question is more focused on how to actually write down the proposition such that I can see why it can be proven by induction, I think the actual proof details don't matter.

Comment: You could for instance prove by induction on $n$ the statement $P(n)$: every connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek If one would write this down formally, the statement would include other quantifiers, wouldn't it? Meaning, the property $P$ would not only depend on $n$, but also on $e$, if you decide to call the number of edges by e, as well as a quantifier for the graphs. Is this a problem? Meaning, can the Property $P$ also include other variables? Thanks.

Comment: Take v =2. There are 2 possible (undirected) graphs (without cycles).  e=1 makes a connected graph e=2 does not.  Take v = 3, now, you are really just adding a vertex to any of the previous graphs (there were only 2, and only 1 satisfying our criteria) and the possible edges that can be added are from the new vertex to any existing vertex. In order to create a connected graph you must connect the new vertex to one of the existing vertices, thus adding another edge. so e (+1) > v(+1)-2

Comment: The property P depends only on $n$. Other variables like $G$ or $e$ or anything else you introduce will be local variables inside P.